# SQL/JS How to re-arrange duplicate rows into one

Tags: php, jquery, sql

How can I regroup all cells that belongs to `User 2` into one row just like for `User 1` and `User 3`?

So instead of having multiple rows for the same user `id`, the script should group them into one row for `User 2` displaying all indicated orange cells accordingly.

The table is dynamically created from PHP code  
However, if it can be done with an SQL statement that would be great, otherwise a jQuery or JS code can regroup it after it's loaded would also help, any ideas?

```
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="whois-onleave" style="font-size:10px;">
      <thead>
        <tr style="text-align: center;font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: large"><td>July 2017</td></tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class=" currentday-bg dayoff"><b>Sat</b></td><td class=" dayoff"><b>Sun</b></td><td><b>Mon</b></td><td><b>Tue</b></td><td><b>Wed</b></td><td><b>Thu</b></td><td><b>Fri</b></td><td class=" dayoff"><b>Sat</b></td><td class=" dayoff"><b>Sun</b></td><td><b>Mon</b></td><td><b>Tue</b></td><td><b>Wed</b></td><td><b>Thu</b></td><td><b>Fri</b></td><td class=" dayoff"><b>Sat</b></td><td class=" dayoff"><b>Sun</b></td><td><b>Mon</b></td><td><b>Tue</b></td><td><b>Wed</b></td><td><b>Thu</b></td><td><b>Fri</b></td><td class=" dayoff"><b>Sat</b></td><td class=" dayoff"><b>Sun</b></td><td><b>Mon</b></td><td><b>Tue</b></td><td><b>Wed</b></td><td><b>Thu</b></td><td><b>Fri</b></td><td class=" dayoff"><b>Sat</b></td><td class=" dayoff"><b>Sun</b></td><td><b>Mon</b></td>    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="12"><b>Employee</b></td>
          <td class=" currentday-bg dayoff"><b>1</b></td><td class=" dayoff"><b>2</b></td><td><b>3</b></td><td><b>4</b></td><td><b>5</b></td><td><b>6</b></td><td><b>7</b></td><td class=" dayoff"><b>8</b></td><td class=" dayoff"><b>9</b></td><td><b>10</b></td><td><b>11</b></td><td><b>12</b></td><td><b>13</b></td><td><b>14</b></td><td class=" dayoff"><b>15</b></td><td class=" dayoff"><b>16</b></td><td><b>17</b></td><td><b>18</b></td><td><b>19</b></td><td><b>20</b></td><td><b>21</b></td><td class=" dayoff"><b>22</b></td><td class=" dayoff"><b>23</b></td><td><b>24</b></td><td><b>25</b></td><td><b>26</b></td><td><b>27</b></td><td><b>28</b></td><td class=" dayoff"><b>29</b></td><td class=" dayoff"><b>30</b></td><td><b>31</b></td>    </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>User 1</td>
          <td class=" currentday-bg dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" allaccepted"></td><td class=" allaccepted"></td><td class=" allaccepted"></td><td class=" allaccepted"></td><td class=" allaccepted"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td>    </tr><tr>
        <td>User 2</td>
        <td class=" currentday-bg dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" allrequested"></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td>    </tr><tr>
        <td>User 2</td>
        <td class=" currentday-bg dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" allrequested"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td>    </tr><tr>
        <td>User 2</td>
        <td class=" currentday-bg dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" allrequested"></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td>    </tr><tr>
        <td>User 2</td>
        <td class=" currentday-bg dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" allrequested"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td>    </tr><tr>
        <td>User 2</td>
        <td class=" currentday-bg dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td class=" allrequested"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td>    </tr><tr>
        <td>User 2</td>
        <td class=" currentday-bg dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" allrequested"></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td>    </tr><tr>
        <td>User 3</td>
        <td class=" currentday-bg dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td class=" allaccepted"></td><td class=" allaccepted"></td><td class=" allaccepted"></td><td class=" allaccepted"></td><td class=" dayoff allaccepted"></td><td class=" dayoff allaccepted"></td><td class=" allaccepted"></td><td class=" allaccepted"></td><td class=" allaccepted"></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td class=" dayoff"></td><td></td>    </tr><tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: How is that table created? PHP? Why does it have to be re-arranged on client-side? Any real reason?

Comment: Well, in PHP the code iterate through all leaves taken for all users and take 'leave_from' and 'leave_to' of each user and create a date range, however, since a user could have multiple leaves during one month, this will be displayed in a new row for the same user. I couldn't get to let work better in PHP

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I've included the PHP code to generate the table body, if you can help with the PHP it's even better

Comment: I really think you should "re-orient" you question to make it a SQL question. You objective should be to have all the `status` of an employee on one row **while `$query->fetch`**. Doing that, you will get help from SQL masters of SO. -- I *could* find a way to handle it with jQuery... But to be honnest, it **isn't** the best thing for you.

Comment: You **can** make this all server-side. ;) Focus on another way for your SQL query... Some [`inner join`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) result is probably the key.

Comment: Thank you @LouysPatriceBessette, could you please show me a simple solution in Jquery maybe that will help if no one answered my question with SQL or PHP solutions?

Comment: Okay... Well, meanwhile, I was still working on it, since it is a nice challenge. And I just had something like a working thing [**here**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/NgYqzL?editors=1011) -- If this is good for you, I feel like to post it as an answer.

Comment: Ok I posted it... It works. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like said in comments below your question...
I think you should work on your SQL query to merge the employee infos on server-side.

It has no impact on a table of 3 "users".

But to rely on the client-side to perform such tasks is not good desing...
Performance talking.

Let's think about 500+ employees with each a couple "leave" from and to.

This would make your company a somekind of a summer camp!
        *lol!*

But you have to think performance when coding too...
Coding is like a business.

Okay, enought philosophy...
Here is the jQuery code to "merge" all employee infos on one row:
   *(From the example table provided and assuming the "users" appear in order)*

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var tableRows = $(".table tr");
  console.log(tableRows.length);

  var previousEmployee = tableRows.find("td").last();
  //console.log(previousEmployee.html());

  // Run throught the rows
  tableRows.each(function(){

    var employee = $(this).find("td").first();
    //console.log(employee.html());

    // If we have a second row for the same employee.
    if( employee.html() == previousEmployee.html() ){
      console.log(employee.html());

      // Move the classes to the above row.
      var thisrowTDcollection = employee.parent("tr").find("td");
      for(j=0;j<thisrowTDcollection.length;j++){
        var classtoMove = thisrowTDcollection.eq(j).attr("class");
        employee.parent("tr").prev().find("td").eq(j).addClass(classtoMove);
      }

      // Now remove this row.
      $(this).remove();

    }
    previousEmployee = employee;
  });
});
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/NgYqzL?editors=1111)

Comment: Thanks! If there is no "lag" issue... It can stay like this. Up to you to test it. That is a loop through rows... And an inner loop through cells. That is why I was wondering about performance. ;)